# Question related to Galois covering of Projective line over rational numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, galois-theory, inverse-problems

Suppose that we have Galois covering $$X\longrightarrow P^{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$$ defined over the rationals which is cyclic, in the sense that the Galois group associated to the covering is a cyclic group. 
Then $X$ can not be $P^{1}_\mathbb{Q}$. I read this result somewhere. Is this result true? I tried this over the complex numbers and I found that over complex numbers it is true:

$P^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} \longrightarrow P^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ defined by $z$ going to $z^{n}$.

Comment: In your example, if you take $n=2$, that is, take the map $z\mapsto z^2$, then the double cover $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Q}^1$, and the map is clearly Galois. So possibly you want your cover to be cyclic of order at least 3?

Comment: yes Sir , you are right actually sorry for mistake.

Comment: Personally, whenever someone with strange sentence structure and grammar uses "Sir", I automatically picture a Nigerian prince (ie, a scammer). Of course I doubt any scammer would be asking questions about galois covers of projective lines, but in any case, mathoverflow is not a very formal venue, so there's no need to address anyone as "Sir".

Comment: @rtz , Sorry for any mistakes. English is not my native language. Anyway Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @rtz I have noticed that a lot of Indians use "Sir" a lot on the internet. I am not entirely sure why this is - probably a symptom of Indian culture where respect towards seniors/elders is of paramount importance. (I myself grew up in India but in an urban, essentially westernized family)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your (!)* [MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/244541/action-of-mathbbz-3-mathbbz-on-p1) (together with the answer/comments) shows that the group of order $3$ is also a Galois group of a Galois cover $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Q}\to\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Q}$. Besides this and order $2$, the only other possible order is $4$ which can be seen as follows:

As $\text{Aut}_{\mathbb Q}(P^1_{\mathbb Q})=\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb Q)$, your question reduces to finding elements of finite order in $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb Q)$. Let $A\in\text{GL}_2(\mathbb Q)$ represent an element of order $m$ in $\text{PGL}_2(\mathbb Q)$. Then $A$ is diagonalizable over a quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Then $\zeta=a/b$ is a primitive $m$-th root of unity. Together with the fact that $\zeta$ has degree at most $2$ over the rationals, one gets $m\le4$ (e.g. by using the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomials, or by more elementary means).

The order $4$ indeed arises, as $z\mapsto(z-1)/(z+1)$ has order $4$ on $\mathbb P^1_{\mathbb Q}$.